# Gremlin InMemory Client on TinkerGraph

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3, tinkergraph

In my java project, I can create in-memory "`GraphTraversalSource`" and I can create traversal queries easily. But I wonder how can I create script queries like `client.submit(query)`?

```
public GraphTraversalSource gremlinGraph()
{
    final Graph graph = TinkerGraph.open();
    return graph.traversal();
}
```

I need a create `Client` object from TinkerGraph. Then I want to call `client.submit(query)` queries.

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the easiest way is to reference the `gremlin-groovy` module and create a `GremlinGroovyScriptEngine` instance ([source code](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.4.10/gremlin-groovy/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/groovy/jsr223/GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java)). Then you can just do:

```
Graph graph = TinkerGraph.open();
ScriptEngine engine = new GremlinGroovyScriptEngine();
Bindings b = new SimpleBindings();
b.put("g", graph);
Traversal t = (Traversal) engine.eval("g.V()", b);
```

Note that `client.submit()` is meant to submit Gremlin to a Gremlin Server compliant system. To use TinkerGraph in that context would mean hosting TinkerGraph in Gremlin Server.

Comment: This does not solve my problem. But it looks a good suggestion.

Comment: there is no way to "create a `Client` object from TinkerGraph". i read your question as wanting a way to process Gremlin scripts in your applications. i'm not sure how else to interpret your problem. perhaps you should restate it?

Comment: stephen, can I convert traversal(coming from engine.eval) to ResultSet or Result like `client.submit() return type`(coming from typical client...)?

Comment: `Client.submit(Traversal)` - but i can't envision why you would do this. it sounds like have a more complicated approach than you need.

Comment: In here, my aim is so simple; to write unit tests for Client. I want to use engine.eval("query") on test; use client.submit("query") on production. In here, query will be same execution will be different for test and production.

Comment: By the way, I dont ask `Client.submit(Traversal)` function; I ask that; is there a function like `engine.eval("query") => return ResultSet`. Why ResultSet; because I want to return same results on `test(engine.eval)` and `production(client.submit)`.

Comment: i understand now. thank you. sadly no, there is no good way to do what you want. we have an open ticket for this problem though: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2428 Note that `ResultSet` does return `Iterable` - perhaps you can use that interface for now somehow?